# Windows authentication in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-mvc-4, windows-authentication

I want to check the login name of a user using windows authentication.
I have this as a constructor of my controller:

```
public class HomeController : BaseController
{
    public string UserIdentityName;

    public HomeController()
    {
        UserIdentityName = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;// HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
    }
}
```

But UserIdentityName returns empty string...

I also have this at my web.config:

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
```

any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't try to access any HttpContext related stuff in your controller's constructor. The earliest stage where you should be accessing it is [Initialize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.initialize%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) method or inside the controller actions.

For example:

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    string user = User.Identity.Name;
    ...
}
```

Also make sure that you have enabled Windows Authentication (NTLM) on your web server.

Comment: You probably haven't configured your web server to require Windows Authentication.

Comment: There's a checkbox that allows you to enable Windows Authentication in Cassini in the `Web` tab of the properties of your project. Did you enable it? At least there's such checkbox in VS2012. I can't remember if older versions of Cassini even support Windows Authentication. I would strongly recommend you to use IIS Express instead.

Comment: I published to IIS (6.5 in my case) unchecked anonymous acccess and chosen windows authentication . still no luck

Comment: So you have a controller action decorated with the `[Authorize]` attribute and you are getting null for the `User.Identity.Name` assuming you have unchecked anonymous access and checked Windows Authentication? Now that's weird as this should work.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov this is significant as I had a scenario where IE picked up User.Identity.Name in my controller action but Chrome didn't and lost the User.Identity info the moment the action was hit! ([Authorize] attribute wasn't present). After I added it, problem solved (so i could round about kiss you right now!)! I'm using Windows authentication and I'm trying to find out WHY this works and why (if a user was authenticated) the info would be lost in the controller action?

Answer (score 14):

In solution explorer pane **select the Web Project and hit F4**. (not right click+properties, thats different)

In properties Pane set:
**Windows Authentication**: Enable 
**Anonymous Authentication**: Disabled

In Web.config: `<authentication mode="Windows"></authentication>`

To get Username:

```
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name OR User.Identity.Name
```

Run your project, Happy Days!

Comment: Double check.  I made this mistake - There are TWO settings Anonymous Authentication at the top and Windows Authentication at the bottom of Project Properties.  I had create a dummy Intranet MVC application and read the readme.txt to realize.

Answer (score 3):

Chaps,

if you are running in IISExpress. Make sure the following setting as below:

In web.config

```
<authentication mode="Windows"/>
<authorization>
  <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
```

open the projectName.csproj in notepad and correct the follwing settings:

```
<IISExpressAnonymousAuthentication>disabled</IISExpressAnonymousAuthentication>
<IISExpressWindowsAuthentication>enabled</IISExpressWindowsAuthentication>

<UseIIS>True</UseIIS>
```

Comment: Above answer editing the file .csproj is working for me. Thanks @Radim

Answer (score 1):

Try adding:

```
<authorization>
  <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
```

to deny access to anonymous users.