# How is the claim inserted into HttpContext.Current.User?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity

When I am debugging my ASP.NET MVC application, I find that there is a lot of information in HttpContext.Current.User. As the pictures below show.(I cannot paste pictures directly in my question, I can only offer the link. Maybe someone can help edit my question?)

[The fist picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXLix.png)

[The second picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4gpos.png)

When and how the claims are inserted into the User object? I can understand that vcn\v0cn430 is my domain name, IIS can get this and insert it into the User object in some step of the pipeline events.

But what is the admin? Is it a windows AD group? I don't think my domain has such a group. Why? Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Windows Authentication, this is the currently logged on user.

The values are read from your Active Directory.

Also, you can use:

```
User.Identity.Name;
```

[Windows authentication in MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12552950/windows-authentication-in-mvc)

Your application itself can issue claims, using application level names such as 'Admin' as security tokens. 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff359101.aspx

Comment: But you can see it in Picture 2, there is also a claim as Admin. there is no such AD group. Actually it is a role defined in database. My question is, how is this one inserted into the HttpContext.Current.User?

Comment: Have you logged into the current machine as localhost\Admin and then logged into the website as VCN\v0cn430 ? the link I referred to indicates an issue accessing httpcontext in constructors. Did User.Identity.Name work instead?

Comment: I only logged into the machine as VCN\V0CN430. That Admin is only defined in a database table. So I assume that maybe at some time there is some operation which inserts some claims into the HttpContext.Current.User. But I don't know when and how.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I find that the application includes a IHttpModue implementation. And inside that class, the mothed AuthenticateRequest, this one insert some claims into HttpContext. This is where and how.